# Secure Method for RAID Device Permissions for Network Storage

Tags: permissions, raid, storage

I manage a smallish network that supports a dozen or so employees. We have about 8 TB of data that lives on several NAS devices. I built a 20 TB RAID file server (with a XFS single partition) recently and we are migrating to this.

The current devices are heterogeneous in their permissions: some storage is internal hard drives mounted on Windows 7; some is a Drobo attached by USB to Ubuntu; and a couple others are Snap Servers, which run their own version of UNIX.

Unfortunately, the network workstations are also heterogeneous, as well. We have Linux, Mac OS and Windows XP/Vista/7/8. This has caused a bit of confusion amongst the users in terms of permissions. As a result, I have basically made storage pretty loose, against my better judgement.

With this new system, the array is mounted on a Linux system and all the storage will be on this device. Thus, I have an opportunity to set it up correctly the first time.

This is where my question comes in. What is the best way to do this? Should I create users for everyone (in a group) on network and force them to connect with these credentials? Should I set the permissions to `777` and keep it open? Or is there a better way to accomplish some level of security but also make it easy for my users to have read/write access to the share?

**EDIT**

From comment, I'd like to update for clarity. I'm sharing with Samba. And the kind of problem I'm seeing is ownership of files and folders.

For example, if I create users (in a group) on the server that correspond to each users' credentials on their workstations, this works OK for permissions, eg, everyone can access and edit files but the ownership is different for files/folders each user created. This causes a problem, since the share should really be writeable by all users, and each user is given the OK to delete folders at their discretion.

Comment: You didn't wrote anything, how do you share the data. I think you do this with samba and nfs. First: security means in the day-to-day work mostly to make your system dummy because of your illusions and fears. It is not always so, but unneeded security restrictions cause today a lot of more harm as the _real_ cracks. Second: I suggest to try a google for "setfacl tutorial", I think the ACL-s are what you really need. They are compatible with samba, too.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think I know the basics of ACL and I have the share in working order, but there are certain aspects that aren't that great. It might be that what I'm looking for isn't really achievable. Thus, my question is what is the best way to get most of what I want?

Comment: What are the aspect of the acls, what you don't like? If you use all of its features (incl. default acls on directories), I can't imagine a situation, which it weren't able to handle. Although even its complexity makes this a little bit hard to learn and automatize. Samba can even convert the windows domain object permissions to acls. Your problem about the file ownerships can be handled by group setgids on the directories. If the directory has a setgid, the newly created files in it will be created with the group of the directory, and not with the group of the creator.

Comment: chmod g+s /the/shared/dir

Comment: Thank you. Why not formulate an answer that encapsulates what you've commented so that I might accept it? I'm asking the question genuinely because I don't know the best way to do what I want. I think you've almost answered the entire question with the comments you've posted...  Might as well get some reputation for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the aspect of the acls, what you don't like? If you use all of its features (incl. default acls on directories), I can't imagine a situation, which it weren't able to handle. Although even its complexity makes this a little bit hard to learn and automatize. Samba can even convert the windows domain object permissions to acls. Your problem about the file ownerships can be handled by group setgids on the directories. If the directory has a setgid, the newly created files in it will be created with the group of the directory, and not with the group of the creator.

chmod g+s /the/shared/dir

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. After reading up on ACLs based on your recommendation, the `chmod g+s` option seems appropriate. Basically, most of my system works pretty good. The only time it fails is when I have a user who technically is allowed to delete a folder cannot because of the way I have the permissions set up. Using the set ID on execution is perfect for my purposes... Thanks.